# Trouble loading custom element action (menu option)

Tags: plugin-development, elementaction

How do you load a custom element action using getAvailableActions inside my Element Type class?

```
public function getAvailableActions($source = null)
{
    $customAction = craft()->elements->getAction('Custom');

    $customAction->setParams(array(
        'label' => Craft::t('Custom'),
    ));

    $actions[] = $customAction;
}
```

The above renders a PHP error **PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setParams() on a non-object**

*PluginName_CustomElementAction* is my file inside the *elementactions* folder, inside my plugin. Which is copied directly from https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/element-actions

Here's what it looks like:

```
namespace Craft;
class PluginName_CustomElementAction extends BaseElementAction
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return Craft::t('Custom');
    }

    public function isDestructive()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function performAction(ElementCriteriaModel $criteria)
    {
        // Remove all the ingredients from the selected elements
        $elements = $criteria->find();

        foreach ($elements as $element)
        {
            craft()->cocktailRecipes->removeAllIngredientsFromElement($element);
        }

        // Success!
        $this->setMessage(Craft::t('Ingredients removed successfully.'));
        return true;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my getAvailableActions object?

Comment: What's the code in your `getAvailableActions` method?  It'd probably help to share what's in your main element class as well.

Comment: @BradBell- just edited the first part to show the function. I can share the full file/plugin privately if this isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue may be that the ElementsService [`getAction`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/ElementsService#getAction-detail) method expects *the full classname* for your custom ElementAction (sans the "ElementAction" suffix), i.e.

```
$customAction = craft()->elements->getAction('PluginName_Custom');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to follow the guide in the docs. https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/element-actions

**Update:** There's a dedicated section about "Adding actions to index pages".

> If your Element Action is intended for your own custom Element Type, you can do that by implementing the [getAvailableActions()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/elementtypes/IElementType#getAvailableActions-detail) method on your Element Type class.

The link takes you to the method's documentation.

```php
/**
 * Returns the available element actions for a given source (if one is provided).
 *
 * The actions can either be represented by their class handle (e.g. 'SetStatus'), or by an
 * instance.
 *
 * @param string|null $source The selected source’s key, if any.
 *
 * @return array|null The available element actions.
 */
public function getAvailableActions($source = null);
```

It's also explained how to implement actions for Craft’s built-in Element Types.

> […] Craft’s built-in Element Types: [addEntryActions](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addEntryActions), [addCategoryActions](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addCategoryActions), …

There's example code provided if you click those links.

```php
public function addEntryActions($source)
{
    return array(
        'Foo',
        new BarElementAction(),
    );
}
```

Comment: Yep. That was copied into PluginName_CustomElementAction. My question actually centers around getAvailableActions and why my custom action isn't an object.

Comment: Only wanted to help. Sorry.

Comment: Very kind reaction of you down voting me and my attempt to do so!

Comment: Didn't mean to offend but I don't think it's relevant unless there is an issue with the action file. This isn't documented very well and I used what was made available.

Comment: So you really want to tell me, the element actions guide with a dedicated section about "Adding actions to index pages" isn't relevant? There's links to the methods with further explanations and example code, it states you should return an array of IElementAction instance or the handles representing them. But yeah, not relevant, even misleading so we better down vote!